# Unknown database 'bwapp'

Tags: php

I'm running windows 10, I'm using XAMPP as my web/sql server.

I downloaded bwapp, extracted the zipped file, edited bwapp\admin\setting.php file and altered db password to null, and lastly I hosted the bwapp folder in my localhost htdocs\ so I can access it through the web browser as shown in below image.
[bWAPP installation page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIa76.png)

However when I click on the installation link (here), I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown database 'bwapp' in C:\xampp\htdocs\bWAPP_latest\bWAPP\install.php:40 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\bWAPP_latest\bWAPP\install.php(40): mysqli_select_db(Object(mysqli), 'bWAPP') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\bWAPP_latest\bWAPP\install.php on line 40

So I went to install.php line 40 to view the code, here it is:

```
    // Checks if the database 'bWAPP' already exists
if(!mysqli_select_db($link,"bWAPP"))
{

    // Creates the database 'bWAPP'
    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS bWAPP";

    $recordset = $link->query($sql);

    if(!$recordset)
    {

        die("Error: " . $link->error);

    }

    // Selects the database 'bWAPP'
     mysqli_select_db($link,"bWAPP");

    // Creates the 'users' table
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,login varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,password varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,";
    $sql.= "email varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,secret varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,activation_code varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,activated tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',";
    $sql.= "reset_code varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,admin tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1";

    $recordset = $link->query($sql);

    if(!$recordset)
    {

        die("Error: " . $link->error);

    }

    // Populates the table 'users' with the default users
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (login, password, email, secret, activation_code, activated, reset_code, admin) VALUES";
    $sql.= "('A.I.M.', '6885858486f31043e5839c735d99457f045affd0', 'bwapp-aim@mailinator.com', 'A.I.M. or Authentication Is Missing', NULL, 1, NULL, 1),";
    $sql.= "('bee', '6885858486f31043e5839c735d99457f045affd0', 'bwapp-bee@mailinator.com', 'Any bugs?', NULL, 1, NULL, 1)";

    $recordset = $link->query($sql);

    if(!$recordset)
    {

        die("Error: " . $link->error);

    }

    // Creates the table 'blog' 
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blog (id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,owner varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,";
    $sql.= "entry varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,date datetime DEFAULT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1";

    $recordset = $link->query($sql);

    if(!$recordset)
    {

        die("Error: " . $link->error);

    }

    // Creates the table 'visitors'
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS visitors (id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,ip_address varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,";
    $sql.= "user_agent varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,date datetime DEFAULT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1";

    $recordset = $link->query($sql);             

    if(!$recordset)
    {

        die("Error: " . $link->error);

    }      
    
    // Creates the table 'movies' 
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS movies (id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,title varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,";
    $sql.= "release_year varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,genre varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,main_character varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,";
    $sql.= "imdb varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,tickets_stock int(10) DEFAULT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1";

    $recordset = $link->query($sql);

    if(!$recordset)
    {

        die("Error: " . $link->error);

    }

    // Populates the table 'movies'
    $sql = "INSERT INTO movies (title, release_year, genre, main_character, imdb, tickets_stock) VALUES ('G.I. Joe: Retaliation', '2013', 'action', 'Cobra Commander', 'tt1583421', 100),";
    $sql.= "('Iron Man', '2008', 'action', 'Tony Stark', 'tt0371746', 53),";
    $sql.= "('Man of Steel', '2013', 'action', 'Clark Kent', 'tt0770828', 78),";
    $sql.= "('Terminator Salvation', '2009', 'sci-fi', 'John Connor', 'tt0438488', 100),";
    $sql.= "('The Amazing Spider-Man', '2012', 'action', 'Peter Parker', 'tt0948470', 13),";
    $sql.= "('The Cabin in the Woods', '2011', 'horror', 'Some zombies', 'tt1259521', 666),";
    $sql.= "('The Dark Knight Rises', '2012', 'action', 'Bruce Wayne', 'tt1345836', 3),";
    $sql.= "('The Fast and the Furious', '2001', 'action', 'Brian O\'Connor', 'tt0232500', 40),";
    $sql.= "('The Incredible Hulk', '2008', 'action', 'Bruce Banner', 'tt0800080', 23),";
    $sql.= "('World War Z', '2013', 'horror', 'Gerry Lane', 'tt0816711', 0)";

    $recordset = $link->query($sql);

    if(!$recordset)
    {

        die("Error: " . $link->error);

    }
    
    // Creates the 'heroes' table
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS heroes (id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,login varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,password varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,secret varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,";
    $sql.= "PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1";

    $recordset = $link->query($sql);             

    if(!$recordset)
    {

            die("Error: " . $link->error);

    }

    // Populates the table 'heroes' with the default users
    $sql = "INSERT INTO heroes (login, password, secret) VALUES";
    $sql.= "('neo', 'trinity', 'Oh why didn\'t I took that BLACK pill?'),";
    $sql.= "('alice', 'loveZombies', 'There\'s a cure!'),";
    $sql.= "('thor', 'Asgard', 'Oh, no... this is Earth... isn\'t it?'),";
    $sql.= "('wolverine', 'Log@N', 'What\'s a Magneto?'),";
    $sql.= "('johnny', 'm3ph1st0ph3l3s', 'I\'m the Ghost Rider!'),";
    $sql.= "('seline', 'm00n', 'It wasn\'t the Lycans. It was you.')";

    $recordset = $link->query($sql);

    if(!$recordset)
    {

            die("Error: " . $link->error);

    }


    $message = "bWAPP has been installed successfully!";

}

else
{

    $message = "The bWAPP database already exists...";

}
```

Note: That is part of setting.php file, contact me if you need the entire thing.

From what I understood, the code checks whether bWAPP database exists or no, if it doesn't, it creates it, yet I cant see where is the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bWAPP version is not compatible with PHP 8.1. Please contact the developer and submit a bug report with them.

As a workaround, you can use PHP 8.0 or older. It might also work if you manually execute `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS bWAPP` in MySQL client, but that doesn't guarantee that the rest of the app will work.

Comment: Yes exactly, after an entire day of troubleshooting, I decided to use an older version of php as the documentation that I am following doesn't use a new version. Thus, I uninstalled XAMPP (latest version - 8.1.6) and install an older version that provide an older php version (7.4.29).

Answer (score 0):

I Tried to change the code from line 40 a bit, so so I wouldn't have to downgrade version of PHP.

```
// Checks if the database 'bWAPP' already exists
try{
    mysqli_select_db($link,"bWAPP");
    $dbex = TRUE;
}catch (Exception $e){
    $dbex = FALSE;
}

if(!$dbex)
{
```

Not the best solution, but it worked fine enough to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue in latest php by turning off mysqli reporting as shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-JQfQU3_mg

I was using PHP 8 and this solution seemed to work for me.

Comment: Please don't link to Youtube videos or other external sites as they can be changed, moved, deleted, ... Rather include a short summary of the video contents / what is to do in your answer. You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34999509)